Handling TaskCanceledException by IExceptionHandler
I'm trying to implement a generic timeout for my requests in C#. I'm aware of the request timeout middleware, but it can't be instructed (as the middleware is handling the exception) to pass the exception so that our normal problem middleware (wrapping it in ProblemDetails) can handle it. So I rolled a simple one to start with:
public class CancelInTimeMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    // Better understanding of why we can't stop all requests very easiliy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52660992/619465
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var originalCt = context.RequestAborted;
        using (var timoutTS = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(originalCt))
        {
            timoutTS.CancelAfter(10000);       // Always cancel after 10 seconds
            context.RequestAborted = timoutTS.Token;
            await next(context);
        }
    }
}

And a simple endpoint:
    public static async Task<IResult> GetTimer(int delaySeconds, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      logger.LogInformation("Entering the wait!");
      await Task.Delay(delaySeconds * 1000, cancellationToken);

        //catch (TaskCanceledException) -> I also want to handle cases where this is forgotten.

        return Results.Json(new { Message = "Waiting is done" });
    }

So I added this simple IExceptionHandler (thank you SO):
class SimpleExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(
        HttpContext httpContext,
        Exception exception,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Your response object
        var error = new { message = exception.Message };
        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(error, cancellationToken);
        return true;
    }
}

And registered it like this:
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<SimpleExceptionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CancelInTimeMiddleware>();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseExceptionHandler(_ => { });
app.UseMiddleware<CancelInTimeMiddleware>();
app.MapGet("wait/{delaySeconds:int}", TestEndPointsImplementations.GetTimer);
app.Run();


It does work for other exceptions that I throw: but not when the cancellation is done. Is this because the request pipeline stops when the CancellationToken is triggered?

it can't be instructed to rethrow the exception what do you mean? What exception do you want to rethrow, why and how do you expect it to be handled? Runaway exceptions are a bad thing. Cancelling doesn't mean an exception will be thrown either. Exceptions are expensive. The whole point of a CancellationToken is to allow checking it and gracefully exiting if it's signaled.

Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos: I updated the question to be a bit clearer on that. I would like a proper ProblemDetails and we already have great middleware to write that. Given that an exception is already thrown on Cancellation it would make sense to just handle that in our normal exception handlers.

There's a standard ProblemDetails response already, generated automatically from validation failures. It's not meant to return every kind of error like timeouts though. . an exception is already thrown on Cancellation that's not the case. Middleware should check for cancellation, not throw. There's a debate what the correct status code for a timeout is but a ProblemDetails response is certainly not correct

You still haven't explained why you don't use the request timeout middleware, which already returns 504. If you insist on returning a ProblemDetails response, the  correct way is to use the ResponseTimeoutPolicy.WriteTimeoutResponse callback, not try to force the cancellation token to throw just so another middleware can convert that to a response

Interesting take: I think the ProblemDetails is much broader than only validation failures: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807 (of course you keep sending the original status code).

You are right that I could use the WriteTimeoutResponse, thanks for adding it to the discussion. This could work: but it would require me to fiddle around to reuse the other middleware that we already have. I might switch to that option, but I also would just like to understand why specifically the TaskCanceledException is never arriving in my current setup (I'm curious :-)).

You keep trying to find an exception where none exists. And if there was one, it would be  most likely be OperationTimeoutException, not  TaskCanceledException. The way your code is written TaskCancelledException won't be thrown. The only way you'd get that exception is if Task.Delay got cancelled before the request, which won't happen except by random chance. IF the delay is more than 10s, the request is aborted and the action has to gracefully handle the termination. The response is already sent. If the delay is less than 10s, there's no cancellation

The ad-hoc strategy (what you call fiddling) is what you're trying to do now - use exceptions to communicate between middleware so you can reuse the code in one of them. Extract that code into a separate method or class instead and call it from both methods

You are wrong on the exception: I see it throwing in 'my' simple endpoint code. Also check Microsofts timeout middleware source code: It's using exceptions as it's mechanism. Btw. TaskCanceledException inherits OperationTimeoutException.
